# How to append keys which are not previously in dataframe 1 but are in dataframe 2 against each name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe df1 like this

```
    id  name  day  marks  mean_marks  
0   1  John  Wed     28          28  
1   1  John  Fri     30          30  
2   2  Alex  Fri     40          50  
3   2  Alex  Fri     60          50
```

and another dataframe df2 as:

```
    day  we
 0  Mon  29
 1  Wed  21
 2  Fri  31
```

now when i do :

```
z = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['day']).fillna(0)
```

i got:

```
    id  name  day  marks  mean_marks    we
0  1.0  John  Wed   28.0        28.0    21
1  1.0  John  Fri   30.0        30.0    31
2  2.0  Alex  Fri   40.0        50.0    31
3  2.0  Alex  Fri   60.0        50.0    31
4  0.0     0  Mon    0.0         0.0    29
```

but i wanted something which would look like :

```
    id  name  day  marks  mean_marks    we
0  1.0  John  Wed   28.0        28.0    21
1  1.0  John  Mon   0.0         0.0     29
2  1.0  John  Fri   30.0        30.0    31
3  2.0  Alex  Mon   0.0         0.0     29
4  2.0  Alex  Wed   0.0         0.0     21
5  2.0  Alex  Fri   40.0        50.0    31
6  2.0  Alex  Fri   60.0        50.0    31
```

that is 'day' which are not previously in df1 but are in df2 should be appended to day against each name.
Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Would you mind to explain why you changed the accepted solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need a `cross join` to create all combinations of days per id and name , then merge should work:

```
u = df1[['id','name']].drop_duplicates().assign(k=1).merge(df2.assign(k=1),on='k')
out = df1.merge(u.drop('k',1),on=['day','name','id'],how='outer').fillna(0)
```

---

```
print(out.sort_values(['id','name']))

   id  name  day  marks  mean_marks  we
0   1  John  Wed   28.0        28.0  21
1   1  John  Fri   30.0        30.0  31
4   1  John  Mon    0.0         0.0  29
2   2  Alex  Fri   40.0        50.0  31
3   2  Alex  Fri   60.0         5.0  31
5   2  Alex  Mon    0.0         0.0  29
6   2  Alex  Wed    0.0         0.0  21
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code should do it:

```python
z = df1.groupby(['name']).apply(lambda grp: grp.merge(df2, how='outer', on='day').
                                fillna({'name': grp.name, 'id': grp.id})).reset_index(drop=True).fillna(0)
```

It gives the following output:

```text
    id  name  day marks mean_marks  we
0  2.0  Alex  Fri    40         50  31
1  2.0  Alex  Fri    60         50  31
2  2.0  Alex  Mon     0          0  29
3  2.0  Alex  Wed     0          0  21
4  1.0  John  Wed    28         28  21
5  1.0  John  Fri    30         30  31
6  1.0  John  Mon     0          0  29
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create df3 with all names and day combination:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[name, day] for name in df1.name.unique() for day in df2.day.unique()], columns=['name', 'day'])
```

Then add id's from df1:

```
df3 = df3.merge(df1[['id', 'name']]).drop_duplicates()[['id', 'name', 'day']]
```

Then add marks and mean marks from df1:

```
df3 = df3.merge(df1, how='left')
```

Then merge:

```
z = df3.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['day']).fillna(0).sort_values('id')
```

Out:

```
    id  name    day marks   mean_marks  we
0   1   John    Mon 0.0     0.0         29
2   1   John    Wed 28.0    28.0        21
4   1   John    Fri 30.0    30.0        31
1   2   Alex    Mon 0.0     0.0         29
3   2   Alex    Wed 0.0     0.0         21
5   2   Alex    Fri 40.0    50.0        31
6   2   Alex    Fri 60.0    50.0        31
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the result ordered by weekdays (within each group by *id*), we should
convert *day* column in both DataFrames to *Categorical* type.
I think, it is better than in your original concept, where you don't care
about the days order.

To  do it, run:

```
wDays = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
days = pd.Categorical(wDays, wDays, ordered=True)
df1.day = df1.day.astype(days)
df2.day = df2.day.astype(days)
```

Then define the following function, performing merge within a group
by *id* and filling *NaN* values (using either *ffill* or *fillna*):

```
def myMerge(grp):
    res = pd.merge(grp, df2, how='right', on=['day'])
    res[['id', 'name']] = res[['id', 'name']].ffill()
    res[['marks', 'mean_marks']] = res[['marks', 'mean_marks']].fillna(0)
    return res.sort_values('day')
```

Then group *df1* by *id* and apply the above function to each group:

```
df1.groupby('id', sort=False).apply(myMerge).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The final step above is *reset_index*, to re-create "ordinary" index.

I added also *sort=False* to keep your desired (original) order of groups.